# Is it possible to clean install Windows 7 on a Sony Vaio laptop when its drivers are no longer supported?

Tags: drivers, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio laptop (with pre-installed Windows Vista). This laptop's drivers are no longer supported by Sony.

Is it possible to do a clean install of Windows 7 on this Sony Vaio Laptop? What would happen when it comes to download drivers?

Alternatively is there a way to save the current drivers to some kind of backup / external drive and reinstall them all back to the laptop when it gets to the stage of downloading / installing drivers?

Would I be facing a situation of a dead laptop if I cannot find and download drivers during the installation?

Comment: Do you have a spare copy of Win 7 lying around (if it's a copy of what's on another computer, you may have trouble activating it), or were you planning to try to buy it?  Win 7 is end-of-life, so if you were successful, you would still have a computer with soon no active support and a potential security risk.  DrMoishe Pippik's suggestion is a good one.  Linux, especially one that comes with a good complement of drivers out of the box, like Ubuntu or Mint, and especially with a lightweight desktop, might give it a better (and current) new lease on life.

Comment: BTW, if your Win 7 is something like an OEM recovery package, it may not have all of the generic drivers in the retail version, it may be mostly limited to what's needed for the hardware it was sold with.  In that case, you might need to find old drivers at places like the hardware manufacturers' web sites.

Comment: @fixer1234 No, not any more. I purchased the Windows 7 Home Premium disk yrs ago & upgraded the laptop, but the disk has been lost. I agree: The most sensible option will be  wipe it & install Linux. I've tried a few different distros, Manjaro & Mint Mate are my preferred ones. I was nevertheless, curious about "what will happen if clean install Win7 when I can't find a way to download the drivers". A shot in the dark, I suppose.

Comment: I found the Win7's product key with Belarc Advisor, in hope that I'd be able to make a Win7 iso image from Microsoft website, never did I knew that Microsoft does not support upgraded Win7 but only preinstalled version. Regarding hardware manufacturers website I will have another look around. Sony's website does not have any drivers for download for my old laptop, they are not joking when they said "cease support".

Comment: This policy is becoming common.  It's harder for manufacturers to get you to buy new hardware if it's easy for you to keep the old stuff running.  :-)

Comment: You are spot on mate! It's sad but another push for me to move away from Windows to Linux I suppose, if I don't wanna chuck the old machine in the bin.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista Drivers are not always (usually not?) compatible with Windows 7. Even though the HW is no longer supported by Sony you still should be able to find the "last" drivers on the Sony website in the support section.

Usually the generic drivers windows comes with are able to run the hardware (although you might not have access to all the features and/or they won't run at "full performance").

I would recommend to make an image of the current System (including the boot record), so you can restore it in case it does not work.

Comment: As @Albin states, make an image so you can go back. You might find a flavor of Linux (such as Ubuntu) to be more compatible with the Vaio than Windows 7, though, and you can test if you like it with a Live USB without having to install it or having to change anything on the HDD.

Comment: Cheers mate. That seems to be the most sensible thing to do with the old machine. I will probably go for Manjaro or Mint Mate. (I've tried a few on Virtual machine on a different pc and have tried persistent USB) I was still having this question in my head: What if I wipe the laptop & reinstall Win7? What will happen when I can't download drivers during the install? I suppose the answer is no.